# change a div css class name of add to result and give it orange color on click

Tags: javascript

change a div css class name of add to result and give it orange color on click

```
function changeclass(){
  var name = document.getElementByClassName("add").name.className = "result",name.color = "orange"
```

Comment: `var div = document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0]; div.classList.remove("add"); div.classList.add("result"); div.style.color = "orange";`

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic:

```
function changeClass(){

  // get the element
  var name = document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0];

  // overwrite the element's existing classname
  name.className = "result";

  // set the element's style attribute with the desired attributes
  name.style.color = "orange";
}
```

It would be better not to set the style attribute directly with JS. You are changing the class from `.add` to `.result`, so it makes more sense to use the class to set the styles:

```
.result {
  color: orange;
}
```